# Defining setter in a shorter way

Tags: python

Currently when I want to define a setter and leave getter alone I do this:

```
@property
def my_property(self):
    return self._my_property

@my_property.setter
def my_property(self, value):
    value.do_some_magic()
    self._my_property = value
```

Is there any way to make it shorter? I'd like to skip this part as it always look the same:

```
@property
def my_property(self):
    return self._my_property
```

Comment: In Python there's always a shorter way. I think you could accomplish something like this with a metaclass, but I don't think it would be worth the complexity or the deviation from standard code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a decorator that auto-creates the getter, following the underscores convention:

```
def setter(fn):
    def _get(self):
        return getattr(self, '_' + fn.__name__)
    def _set(self, val):
        return fn(self, val)
    return property(_get, _set)
```

or more concisely, if you like this style more:

```
def setter(fn):
    return property(
        lambda self: getattr(self, '_' + fn.__name__),
        fn)
```

Usage:

```
class X(object):
    @setter
    def my_property(self, value):
        self._my_property = value + 1

x = X()
x.my_property = 42
print x.my_property # 43
```

Answer (score 6):

There's no out of the box solution, but you can try something like this:

```
def defprop(name):
    def getter(self):
        return getattr(self, name)
    return property(getter)

class C(object):
    # ...
    my_dictionary = defprop('_my_dictionary')
    # ...
```

That does not save you that many keystrokes though, you still have to duplicate the attribute name. Besides it's less explicit.

---

*Update*: after thinking a bit, I've come up with this descriptor-based hackish trick (disclaimer: this is done just for a demonstration, I don't imply it's a good practice unless you have a damn good reason to do so):

```
class with_default_getter(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self._attr_name = '_{0.__name__}'.format(func)
        self._setter = func

    def __get__(self, obj, type):
        return getattr(obj, self._attr_name)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        return self._setter(obj, value)
```

Usage:

```
class C(object):
    @with_default_getter
    def my_property(self, value):
        print 'setting %s'
        self._my_property = value

>>> c = C()
>>> c.my_property = 123
setting 123
>>> c.my_property
123
```

This is pretty much the same as @georg suggests, just unfolds the implementation down to descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

There is no shortcut that I am aware of- remember explicit is better than implicit (from the Zen of python).

It could be that in your code so far, a property is always like that - but you could at some point write a a property getter which fetches an entirely calculated value - in which case your property getter and setter wont look like that at all.

Haveing said that you could write a wrapper which provides those simple default methods as part of the wrapper, if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

```
def set_my_property(self, value):
    value.do_some_magic()
    self._my_property = value

my_property = property(fset=set_my_property)
```